# Interchanging the order of summation

Tags: summation

I want to compute this sum: $$\sum_{S\,\subseteq\,Q} f\left(S\right)$$ where $Q$ is some finite set with $n$ elements. I think the first step should be: $$\sum_{i=0}^{n}\left(\sum_{S\,\subseteq\,Q\,;\,\vert S\vert\, =\,i}f\left(S\right)\right)$$

which can be useful if $f$ depends on $\vert S\vert$. Can the order of summation be interchanged?? I honestly don't know how to do it (if it can be done). The conditions $i=0,1,2,\dots,n$ and $\vert S\vert=i$ don't seem very "compatible" because there is no natural total order in $\{ \,S\subseteq Q:\vert S\vert=i\,\}$

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try it with simple examples. If $Q=\{1,2\}$ or $Q=\{1,2,3\}$, what are the possible inner summation sets of subsets with one subset per magnitude, and do any of them look possibly useful?

Comment: I don't quite get what you mean by interchanging the order of the summations. If we do that, we get:
$$\sum_{S\,\subseteq\,Q\,;\,\vert S\vert\, =\,i}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}f\left(S\right)\right) \stackrel{(*)}{=} \sum_{S\,\subseteq\,Q\,;\,\vert S\vert\, =\,i}\left(n f(S)\right) \stackrel{(**)}{=} \phi(i)$$

$(*)$ since the formula isn't depending on the value of $i$.

$(**) \ \ i$ stays there as a constant of the first summation, so we get some $(\phi)$ function of $i$.

Comment: @DanielP I don't mean "literally" change the two summations, that doesn't make sense here. The answer should depend on $n$ (the size of $Q$). Try looking for related questions to see what I'm trying to do

Comment: @aschepler I don't think it is going to work at least in a nice way. "Organizing" the sets is probably getting harder the larger the size of $Q$

Comment: The set $S$ is the variable of the function $f$? Maybe do you mean $S$ belongs to $Q$ ?

Comment: @dmtri yes. I mean $S$ belongs to the power set of $Q$. $f(S)$ is a function like "number of elements of $S$" or "1 if $5\in S$ and 0 otherwise"

Answer (score 1):

In case the cardinality of the set $Q$ is finite and the function $f$ takes real values,  then adding finite real numbers with any order , would always give the same result-sum.